# Aplicação .NET C# estilo express NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js, express.js, asp.net-web-api

Mas para algumas poucas funcionalidades eu gostaria que meu projeto me responde-se a alguns simples requisições HTTP Rest. Como o projeto vai lidar com COM+ e outras coisas mais, eu irei faze-lo em C#.

A questão é, eu não quero ter que lidar com IIS e queria algo mais simples, como um .exe que possa ser executado e se "auto-hospede".

Algo muito parecido com coisas como Flask para Python, ou Express para Nodejs, em que você determina as rotas, o tipo de método, executa ele e pronto.

Algúem aqui sabe se existe alguma framework para algo similar em .NET?

Comment: Existe o OWIN: http://owin.org/

Comment: Oi Gabriel. Vou olhar a documentação com calma. Agradeço a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brow, de uma olhada nesses dois caras:

O [Asp.net core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/), ele tem um servidor de aplicação próprio que o "auto-hospeda", o kestrel. Por sua simplicidade, basta somente disponibilizar seus recursos através de uma simples API.

Outra opção é a [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/), não conheço muito, mas herda as ideias do Flask, Sinatra e etc, não tenho certeza, mas no final acredito que acabara dependendo de alguém que o sustente como o kestrel ou outro servidor de aplicação.

Comment: Esse Nancy parece ser exatamente o que preciso.